# Where can I find the Bitcoin white paper in plain text markdown format?

Tags: satoshi, whitepaper

Is there a place where I can find the Bitcoin whitepaper by satoshi in plain text markdown format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps convert the whitepaper in pdf to your required format?

A discussion in [pandoc](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/pandoc-discuss/yjfhJ6h47Y0/msK6aAzlrB0J) mentions `pdftohtml -xml` to be most promising.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a markdown version [here](https://github.com/karask/satoshi-paper/blob/master/bitcoin.md).

Answer (score 3):

I recently created a markdown version of the Bitcoin Whitepaper, which you can find at https://github.com/dhimmel/bitcoin-whitepaper/tree/master/content. Most of the markdown text is in [this file](https://github.com/dhimmel/bitcoin-whitepaper/raw/master/content/02.body.md). I based this version off the Whitepaper provided by the [*Satoshi Nakamoto Institute*](http://nakamotoinstitute.org/bitcoin/). Accordingly, the images are SVGs and the math is TeX-formatted.

The source markdown is compiled by the Manubot and served by GitHub pages at http://git.dhimmel.com/bitcoin-whitepaper/. Contributions are welcome if you notice any issues.

For the ODT-formatted whitepaper (in many languages) see https://github.com/saivann/bitcoinwhitepaper.

**Update:** See my [Steemit post](https://steemit.com/manubot/@dhimmel/how-i-used-the-manubot-to-reproduce-the-bitcoin-whitepaper) with more details on how I converted the whitepaper to markdown.